# Can't block AspiegelBot in htaccess or robots.txt

Tags: .htaccess, centos, web-crawler, robots.txt

I have issues with AspiegelBot crawling one of the sites on a server, this results in a lot of cores getting used up. I've been trying to block the bot in both in the sites htaccess with no sucess. The bot still constantly appears in my access.log

```
114.119.165.232 - - [20/Apr/2020:07:38:40 +0200] "GET /tillbehor.html?size=98%2C422%2C423%2C1129%2C1378 HTTP/1.1" 301 296 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0;) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; AspiegelBot)"
```

Here is some of what I've tried:

**htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.(Mb2345Browser|AspiegelBot|LieBaoFast|MicroMessenger|zh-CN|Kinza|Mb2345Browser).$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

**robots.txt**

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Disallow: */shopby

#######################################
################ PAGES ################
#######################################

Disallow: /privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode/
Disallow: /terms/

#######################################
############# Block Bots ##############
#######################################

 User-agent: MJ12bot
 Disallow: /
 User-agent: SemrushBot
 Disallow: /
 User-agent: SemrushBot-SA
 Disallow: /
 User-agent: rogerbot
 Disallow:/
 User-agent: dotbot
 Disallow:/
 User-agent: AhrefsBot
 Disallow: /
 User-agent: Alexibot
 Disallow: /
 User-agent: SurveyBot
 Disallow: /
 User-agent: Xenu's
 Disallow: /
 User-agent: Xenu's Link Sleuth 1.1c
 Disallow: /
 User-agent: AspiegelBot
 Disallow: /
```

Am I missing something or writing something incorrectly? Ï'm kinda at a loss here.

Comment: Your pattern is anchored at the beginning and end, and demands exactly _one_ arbitrary character before and after what you try to match inside the braces, with the `.` meta character. `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0;) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; AspiegelBot)` does not match that format, not by a long shot.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: This is clearly not a SEO question: The OP is trying to stop abusive actions on behalf of a bot.

Comment: I managed to get the bot blocked by blocking the starting IP sequence. It might not be optimal way to do it but it worked.  `Deny from 114.119.0.0/16`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this as a comment but seeing as it's what solved this for me I will add it as an answer.
I managed to get the bot blocked by blocking the starting IP sequence in the htaccess file. It might not be optimal way to do it but it worked.

`Deny from 114.119.0.0/16`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your .htaccess

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

# Block Bad Bots & Scrapers
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^AspiegelBot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Aboundex" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "80legs" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "360Spider" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Java" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Cogentbot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Alexibot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^asterias" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^attach" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^BackDoorBot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^BackWeb" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Bandit" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^BatchFTP" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Bigfoot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Black.Hole" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^BlackWidow" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^BlowFish" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^BotALot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Buddy" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^BuiltBotTough" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Bullseye" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^BunnySlippers" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Cegbfeieh" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^CheeseBot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^CherryPicker" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^ChinaClaw" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Collector" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Copier" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^CopyRightCheck" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^cosmos" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Crescent" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Custo" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^AIBOT" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^DISCo" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^DIIbot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^DittoSpyder" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Download\ Demon" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Download\ Devil" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Download\ Wonder" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^dragonfly" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Drip" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^eCatch" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^EasyDL" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^ebingbong" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^EirGrabber" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^EmailCollector" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^EmailSiphon" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^EmailWolf" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^EroCrawler" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Exabot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Express\ WebPictures" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Extractor" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^EyeNetIE" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Foobot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^flunky" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^FrontPage" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Go-Ahead-Got-It" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^gotit" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^GrabNet" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Grafula" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Harvest" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^hloader" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^HMView" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^HTTrack" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^humanlinks" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^IlseBot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Image\ Stripper" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Image\ Sucker" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Indy\ Library" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^InfoNaviRobot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^InfoTekies" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Intelliseek" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^InterGET" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Internet\ Ninja" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Iria" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Jakarta" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^JennyBot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^JetCar" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^JOC" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^JustView" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Jyxobot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Kenjin.Spider" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Keyword.Density" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^larbin" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^LexiBot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^lftp" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^libWeb/clsHTTP" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^likse" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^LinkextractorPro" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^LinkScan/8.1a.Unix" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^LNSpiderguy" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^LinkWalker" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^lwp-trivial" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^LWP::Simple" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Magnet" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Mag-Net" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^MarkWatch" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Mass\ Downloader" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Mata.Hari" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Memo" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Microsoft.URL" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Microsoft\ URL\ Control" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^MIDown\ tool" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^MIIxpc" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Mirror" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Missigua\ Locator" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Mister\ PiX" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^moget" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Mozilla/3.Mozilla/2.01" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Mozilla.*NEWT" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^NAMEPROTECT" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Navroad" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^NearSite" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^NetAnts" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Netcraft" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^NetMechanic" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^NetSpider" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Net\ Vampire" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^NetZIP" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^NextGenSearchBot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^NG" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^NICErsPRO" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^niki-bot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^NimbleCrawler" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Ninja" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^NPbot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Octopus" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Offline\ Explorer" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Offline\ Navigator" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Openfind" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^OutfoxBot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^PageGrabber" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Papa\ Foto" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^pavuk" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^pcBrowser" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^PHP\ version\ tracker" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Pockey" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^ProPowerBot/2.14" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^ProWebWalker" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^psbot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Pump" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^QueryN.Metasearch" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^RealDownload" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Reaper" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Recorder" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^ReGet" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^RepoMonkey" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^RMA" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Siphon" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^SiteSnagger" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^SlySearch" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^SmartDownload" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Snake" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Snapbot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Snoopy" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^sogou" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^SpaceBison" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^SpankBot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^spanner" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Sqworm" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Stripper" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Sucker" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^SuperBot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^SuperHTTP" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Surfbot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^suzuran" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Szukacz/1.4" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^tAkeOut" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Teleport" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Telesoft" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^TurnitinBot/1.5" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^The.Intraformant" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^TheNomad" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^TightTwatBot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Titan" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^True_Robot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^turingos" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^TurnitinBot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^URLy.Warning" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Vacuum" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^VCI" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^VoidEYE" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Web\ Image\ Collector" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Web\ Sucker" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^WebAuto" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^WebBandit" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Webclipping.com" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^WebCopier" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^WebEMailExtrac.*" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^WebEnhancer" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^WebFetch" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^WebGo\ IS" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Web.Image.Collector" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^WebLeacher" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^WebmasterWorldForumBot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^WebReaper" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^WebSauger" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Website\ eXtractor" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Website\ Quester" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Webster" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^WebStripper" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^WebWhacker" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^WebZIP" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Whacker" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Widow" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^WISENutbot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^WWWOFFLE" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^WWW-Collector-E" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Xaldon" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Xenu" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Zeus" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "ZmEu" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Zyborg" bad_bot

# Vulnerability Scanners
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Acunetix" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "FHscan" bad_bot

# Aggressive Chinese Search Engine
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Baiduspider" bad_bot

# Aggressive Russian Search Engine
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Yandex" bad_bot


<Limit GET POST HEAD>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all

Deny from env=bad_bot
</Limit>
```